# T-SQL : nvarchar to hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an nvarchar field which stores a value which relates to a time.

```
eg
104:45:50 (104 hrs, 45 mins, 50 secs).
```

Any suggestions on how I could convert this into a workable/usable field for calculations?

SQL 'time' only allows upto 23:59:59, hence storing as nvarchar.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: field value could also be 99:45:50 (99 hrs, 45 mins, 50 secs), so 2 or 3 digit hours.

Comment: "_a workable/usable field for calculations_" What kind of calculations? You could just save it as an `int` and store the amount of seconds that goes into that time.

Comment: Just store as a numeric type representing number of hours/minutes/seconds; there is precisely no point in storing things in [h]:mm:ss format (though of course you can convert to that later in the application or report)

Comment: I do like a negative mark against a question instead of a sensible suggestion.  'Store as seconds' - that's sensible, many thanks!

Comment: @underscore_d I agree, I inherited some code that stored duration as a string and although I managed to convert it back to minutes/seconds to perform calculations it was better when I changed the tables to store duration as minutes or seconds and then use an scalar function for getting the string representation (like `dbo.fnSecondsToString(SecondsColumn)`).

Answer (score 0):

String data types are not a good solution for numeric information. In this case working up from seconds will enable output into h:m:s units, but the reverse is an ugly problem.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bb991/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([badcolumn] varchar(9), [num_secs] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([badcolumn])
VALUES
    ('104:45:50'),
    ('99:45:50')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
     badcolumn, (h*3600)+(m*60)+s as num_seconds
from table1
cross apply (
  select
      charindex(':',badcolumn) x
    , charindex(':',badcolumn, charindex(':',badcolumn)+1) y
  ) ca1
cross apply (
  select
       try_cast(substring(badcolumn,1,x-1) as int) h
     , try_cast(substring(badcolumn,x+1,y-x-1) as int) m
     , try_cast(substring(badcolumn,y+1,20) as int) s
  ) ca2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bb991/1/0)**:

```
| badcolumn | num_seconds |
|-----------|-------------|
| 104:45:50 |      377150 |
|  99:45:50 |      359150 |
```